# Cross correlation for extremely highly correlated series

Tags: time-series, cross-correlation, lags

I have two time series showing very high dependency, in the order of 99.99% correlation, and I need to study their lead-lag relationship. So far I've been looking at the Pearson correlation with 7/8 decimals precision, but I wonder if there is a better approach. The problem is that most of the time the series value does not change: changes are concentrated in less than 1% of the observations.

Should I extract a sub-sample based on the value changes in one of the series?